# Is this an awkward ordering of words? (Cantonese)

Tags: word-choice, word, cantonese

In the following sentence: 你要重新開過一次機。
The official translation is: you will have to restart the machine again.

I feel this Has a very awkward word order since the object (機) is at the last after a string of modifiers and other words.

Is this normal? Is there another way to say this from a beginner’s point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

機 is not the object, It is part of the verb phrase "開機" - "turn (machine/ device) on"

Just like "吃飯" is a single verb phrase, where 飯 is not an object.

The sentence is grammatical. Just too wordy.

[(重新) + verb + (過)] is a set structure meaning [(from the start) + verb + (again)] e.g "重新做過" (from the start do it again)

The awkward part is 一次 is kind of redundant, "Do it again" already indicated "do it one more time" , you really don't need  to add "一次" (once) in this sentence.

Either 你要重新開過機 or 你要重新開一次機 (you have to start from the beginning and turn the device on again) would flow much more smoothly

Answer (score 1):

你要重新開過一次機 is not quite standard

你要重新開機 is a standard way to say you have to restart the machine

你要重新開過(一次)機 may have a slightly different meaning of saying
You have to start the machine all over again